# proc summary sas with two classes: manage combinations with types and ways

Tags: sas

I wrote this code to retrieve an aggregated sum of a variable, grouping by month and year.

```
PROC SUMMARY DATA=test.aggr_test; 
  VAR AMOUNT_TRANSACTION; 
  CLASS month year; 
  types month  year;
  ways 2;
  OUTPUT OUT=WORK.SUM_AMOUNT_TRANSACTION
     (DROP= _TYPE_ _FREQ_) sum=;
RUN;
```

[image]

SUM_AMOUNT_TRANSACTION contains these combinations, but I'd rather report only one combination (the plain one, 7/2017). How can I manage that with *types* and *ways* clauses?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `ways` and `types`, try adding `nways` on the proc summary statement line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I prefer is to specify it explicitly in a `type` statement.  You show *interactions* in `type`; so `month*year` shows that you want the combination of month and year considered only (and not month by itself, year by itself, or neither).

You can also accomplish the same with `ways` (you show that in your example, if you had removed `types` it would have worked as you wanted), but unless I'm specifying many type interactions I prefer to write it out explicitly, as it makes it easier to maintain if I later add a class variable but still want the old type combination.

```
PROC SUMMARY DATA=test.aggr_test; 
  VAR AMOUNT_TRANSACTION; 
  CLASS month year; 
  types month*year;
  OUTPUT OUT=WORK.SUM_AMOUNT_TRANSACTION
     (DROP= _TYPE_ _FREQ_) sum=;
RUN;
```